# How do I deploy a Discord Bot in Python to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord.py

Recently, I built a discord bot for my personal server using discord.py. I was able to deploy the bot's code onto heroku using git, but when I deployed the code and tried accessing a function of the bot, I did not receive the response. I know the code works as I tested it locally initially.

The github link is:
https://github.com/ayushboss/Baylor-Discord-Bot

All I did on heroku was click on this github link.

Answer (score 0):

I'll break down the places which breaks the deploy into points-

1. requirements.txt Your requirements file does not have the `==` required. Open CMD in the folder where your heroku python script is stored, and type `pip freeze`. Then copy/paste everything into your requirements.txt file. It should look like [this](https://github.com/Sajo811/turtlecoin-market-linker/blob/master/requirements.txt) in the end.
2. **BOT TOKEN** It doesn't break the deploy, but is very dangerous. Anyone can view your bot token [here](https://github.com/ayushboss/Baylor-Discord-Bot/blob/master/bot.py), which means they have full control over your bot. I recommend making 2 seperate folder for your bot, one pushes to heroku with your token, the other pushes to github with a placeholder for the token

If you build your deploys from github, then you have to pay to get a private repo. I recommend instead pushing from the CLI to heroku and github seperately, it's actually pretty easy.

3. runtime.txt I'm not entirely sure about this, but it's not the latest 
   version(3.6.4) supported. Leaving it be should be OK, so just ignore this

This should fix your deploying issue, if you have a doubt then you can check my [guide](https://github.com/Sajo811/turtlecoin-market-linker#deploying-on-heroku) or just reply to this :)